# How to parse String "24-10-2012" into Date ( dd-mm-yyyy) format?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am using jdk- 1.6.
I am try to parse String "24-10-2012" date to Date (24-10-2012) but i am getting this error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "18-11-2012"
java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:354)
```

I am parsing like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String currentDate = "24-10-2012";
 Date date = formatter.parse(currentDate);
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace, that might help.

Comment: give environment details like jdk version etc

Comment: I think that should work fine. Are you having some other code using Date Formatting nearby? Please post the full stack trace?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not parsing another date somewhere? "18-11-2012" it's not the same that "24-10-2012".

Comment: @DuncanJones that's irrelevant

Comment: @MozenRath Fair point, I guess that would affect the formatter being created, not parsing the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date in java does not hold any format. Read [more...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String currentDate = "24-10-2012";
System.out.println(formatter.parse(currentDate));
```

prints

```
Wed Oct 24 00:00:00 CEST 2012
```

Your problem cannot be reproduced with the code you have posted.

My hypothesis: your exception is thrown from a piece of code other than the one you are accusing of the error. You could try carefully analyzing the stack trace in order to track down the real culprit.

Comment: Thank you, i am getting output as you posted. but i want in dd-mm-yyyy format. how to do this?

Comment: Then what i need to do for this? any suggestion.

Comment: `formatter.format(date)`, as I said. It is the same formatter instance that you have in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When I run

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String currentDate = "24-10-2012";
Date date = formatter.parse(currentDate);
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

I get

```
Wed Oct 24 00:00:00 BST 2012
24-10-2012
```

which is as I expected. Can you clarity what the problem is?

Comment: Thank you, i am getting output as Wed Oct 24 00:00:00 BST 2012. but i want in dd-mm-yyyy format. how to do this?

Comment: I assume you mean `dd-MM-yyyy` as `mm` means minutes. The text is already in that format so your question doesn't make allot of sense but I will update my answer.

Comment: No ,i am getting only Thu Oct 11 00:00:00 IST 2012. MM means Month. i want date in dd-MM-yyyy format.

Comment: If you try the example above you should get two lines.

Comment: @JeetuVerma You are confusing what the date is and how it should be displayed.  A date is has no format and can displayed any way you wish. only displayed as text i.e. a String.  It appears you want to change the default format for the `Date` class, something I assure yous is a) not a good idea b) highly unlikely to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the format "dd-mm-yyyy"

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
    String currentDate = "24-10-2012";
    Date date = formatter.parse(currentDate);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Date doesnot have any formats. It represents the instance in time

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class SimpleFormatDate
{
  public static void main(String args[]){
  Date todaysDate = new java.util.Date();
  // Formatting date into  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss e.g 2008-10-10 11:21:10

  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  String formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);
  System.out.println("Formatted date is ==>"+formattedDate);

  // Formatting date into  yyyy-MM-dd e.g 2008-10-10 
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);
  System.out.println("Formatted date is ==>"+formattedDate);

  // Formatting date into  MM/dd/yyyy e.g 10/10/2008 
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  formattedDate = formatter.format(todaysDate);
  System.out.println("Formatted date is ==>"+formattedDate);
  }
}
```

output

```
Formatted date is ==>2008-10-10 13:03:54
Formatted date is ==>2008-10-10
Formatted date is ==>10/10/2008
```

Answer (score -1):

Wait a second.. Why u need to parsing that if u have a right value ?
Anyway, i use this :

```
SimpleDateFormat oFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String sDate = oFormat.format("24-10-2012");
```

it will appearing date like 2012-10-24. So if u want to parsing to dd-MM-yyyy, u just need change the format to what u want.

NB : Sorry if my english is bad. :D

Comment: Not the downvoter, but - You parse Date in string form to get Date object. And you format your Date object to get String representation

Comment: *sigh* downvoter for the reasons mentioned in the comments above.